# Alfresco Production Enviroment what is Size for maxDocsForInMemoryMerge

Tags: lucene, alfresco

Having two Different production Alfresco (3.3.5 and 4.0.2) System. We have set 
`maxDocsForInMemoryMerge=40000` and `maxDocsForInMemoryIndex=16000`.

Heap Size increase to 18 GB and then server responds slow. We have to restart server weekly to serve production users.

When Profile came to know that Lucene is using more memory on server. on some links found solution to set `maxDocsForInMemoryMerge=0` but not sure about the results.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Those numbers look huge! Where did you get them from?

Comment: Default values for these two properties are both 10000. Did you try with this value?

Comment: @Gagravarr- We used those values for Full-Reindexing with consultation of Alfresco. And using since from then.

Comment: @abarisone- Earlier it was set to 10000 only but Full-reindexing was slow during Migration of 2.1.1 to 4.0.2 and we got those # from Alfresco.

Comment: Ring Alfresco support up again, and ask them to advise you on what to use at runtime for your setup then?